# Switch to visual storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, view

I have Xcode 4.2 and I am a complete beginner. One of my files is called `MainStoryboard.storyboard`. When I first started working, this showed the different iOS screens pictorially. Now I see (what I presume is the storyboard in) code.

How can I switch back to the visual format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the left-column project Navigator in XCode, Control-click on your Storyboard item and select: Open As -> Interface Builder - iOS Storyboard